# Generate different random number

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to build code for Blackjack game, and I am having the following problem:

I want the the code to not use the same card more than once until it reshuffles (reload all 52 cards again).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <ctime>

#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <time.h> 
using namespace std;
class play_cards

{
public:
    play_cards::play_cards();
    void play_cards::load();
    void play_cards::printdeck();
    void play_cards::startGame();
    void play_cards::reshuffle();
    void play_cards::check();
private:
struct deck
{
    string card_name;
    string card_type;
    int card_value;
    bool dealt;
};
deck card[52];
int i,random, counter ;
double Total;
};
int main()
{ string start="";

    cout<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"The Rules are as Following:"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"1.  The dealer gives one card face up to each player,  "<<endl;
    cout<<"    and then one card face up to himself."<<endl;
    cout<<"2.  Another round of cards is then dealt face up to each player, "<<endl;
    cout<<"    but the dealer takes his second card face down. "<<endl;
    cout<<"3.  Each player must decide whether to "<<endl;
    cout<<"    stand (not ask for another card) "<<endl;
    cout<<"                 OR                  "<<endl;
    cout<<"    hit (ask for another card ) "<<endl;
    cout<<"4.  Each player attempts to beat the dealer by getting a count  closer to 21, "<<endl;


cout<<"    without going over 21. "<<endl;
    cout<<"5.  When the dealer has served the player, his face-down card is turned up. "<<endl;
    cout<<"    If the total is 17 or more, he must stand. 16 or under, he takes a card. "<<endl;
    cout<<"6.  If the dealer has an ace, and counting it as 11 would bring his total to 17"<<endl;
    cout<<"    or more (but not over 21), he must count the ace as 11 and stand. "<<endl;
    cout<<"7.  The dealer's decisions, then, are automatic on all plays,  "<<endl;
    cout<<"    whereas the player always has the option of taking one or more cards. "<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    play_cards value;
    cout<< "Do you want to Start Playing ? (yes / no)"<<endl<<endl;
    cin>>start;
    if(start=="yes"){
    value.startGame();
    }
    //value.printdeck();
    system("pause");
   return 0;
}
play_cards::play_cards()
{
    random=0;
    counter=0;
    Total=0;
}

 void play_cards::load()
    {
    card[0].card_name="TWO";
    card[0].card_type="heart";
    card[0].card_value=2;
    card[0].dealt=false;
    card[1].card_name="THREE";
    card[1].card_type="heart";
    card[1].card_value=3;
    card[1].dealt=false;
    card[2].card_name="FOUR";
    card[2].card_type="heart";
    card[2].card_value=4;
    card[2].dealt=false;
    card[3].card_name="FIVE";
    card[3].card_type="heart";
    card[3].card_value=5;
    card[3].dealt=false;
    card[4].card_name="SIX";
    card[4].card_type="heart";
    card[4].card_value=6;
    card[4].dealt=false;
    card[5].card_name="SEVEN";
    card[5].card_type="heart";
    card[5].card_value=7;
    card[5].dealt=false;
    card[6].card_name="EIGHT";
    card[6].card_type="heart";
    card[6].card_value=8;
    card[6].dealt=false;
    card[7].card_name="NINE";
    card[7].card_type="heart";
    card[7].card_value=9;
    card[7].dealt=false;
    card[8].card_name="TEN";
    card[8].card_type="heart";
    card[8].card_value=10;
    card[8].dealt=false;
    card[9].card_name="ACE";
    card[9].card_type="heart";
    card[9].card_value=1;
    card[9].dealt=false;
    card[10].card_name="JACK";
    card[10].card_type="heart";
    card[10].card_value=10;
    card[10].dealt=false;
    card[11].card_name="QUEEN";
    card[11].card_type="heart";
    card[11].card_value=10;
    card[11].dealt=false;
    card[12].card_name="KING";
    card[12].card_type="heart";
    card[12].card_value=10;
    card[12].dealt=false;

    card[13].card_name="TWO";
    card[13].card_type="diamond";
    card[13].card_value=2;
    card[13].dealt=false;
    card[14].card_name="THREE";
    card[14].card_type="diamond";
    card[14].card_value=3;
    card[14].dealt=false;
    card[15].card_name="FOUR";
    card[15].card_type="diamond";
    card[15].card_value=4;
    card[15].dealt=false;
    card[16].card_name="FIVE";
    card[16].card_type="diamond";
    card[16].card_value=5;
    card[16].dealt=false;
    card[17].card_name="SIX";
    card[17].card_type="diamond";
    card[17].card_value=6;
    card[17].dealt=false;
    card[18].card_name="SEVEN";
    card[18].card_type="diamond";
    card[18].card_value=7;
    card[18].dealt=false;
    card[19].card_name="EIGHT";
    card[19].card_type="diamond";
    card[19].card_value=8;
    card[19].dealt=false;
    card[20].card_name="NINE";
    card[20].card_type="diamond";
    card[20].card_value=9;
    card[20].dealt=false;
    card[21].card_name="TEN";
    card[21].card_type="diamond";
    card[21].card_value=10;
    card[21].dealt=false;
    card[22].card_name="ACE";
    card[22].card_type="diamond";
    card[22].card_value=1;
    card[22].dealt=false;
    card[23].card_name="JACK";
    card[23].card_type="diamond";
    card[23].card_value=10;
    card[23].dealt=false;
    card[24].card_name="QUEEN";
    card[24].card_type="diamond";
    card[24].card_value=10;
    card[24].dealt=false;
    card[25].card_name="KING";
    card[25].card_type="diamond";
    card[25].card_value=10;
    card[25].dealt=false;

    card[26].card_name="TWO";
    card[26].card_type="spade";
    card[26].card_value=2;
    card[26].dealt=false;
    card[27].card_name="THREE";
    card[27].card_type="spade";
    card[27].card_value=3;
    card[27].dealt=false;
    card[28].card_name="FOUR";
    card[28].card_type="spade";
    card[28].card_value=4;
    card[28].dealt=false;
    card[29].card_name="FIVE";
    card[29].card_type="spade";
    card[29].card_value=5;
    card[29].dealt=false;
    card[30].card_name="SIX";
    card[30].card_type="spade";
    card[30].card_value=6;
    card[30].dealt=false;
    card[31].card_name="SEVEN";
    card[31].card_type="spade";
    card[31].card_value=7;
    card[31].dealt=false;
    card[32].card_name="EIGHT";
    card[32].card_type="spade";
    card[32].card_value=8;
    card[32].dealt=false;
    card[33].card_name="NINE";
    card[33].card_type="spade";
    card[33].card_value=9;
    card[33].dealt=false;
    card[34].card_name="TEN";
    card[34].card_type="spade";
    card[34].card_value=10;
    card[34].dealt=false;
    card[35].card_name="ACE";
    card[35].card_type="spade";
    card[35].card_value=1;
    card[35].dealt=false;
    card[36].card_name="JACK";
    card[36].card_type="spade";
    card[36].card_value=10;
    card[36].dealt=false;
    card[37].card_name="QUEEN";
    card[37].card_type="spade";
    card[37].card_value=10;
    card[37].dealt=false;
    card[38].card_name="KING";
    card[38].card_type="spade";
    card[38].card_value=10;
    card[38].dealt=false;

    card[39].card_name="TWO";
    card[39].card_type="club";
    card[39].card_value=2;
    card[39].dealt=false;
    card[40].card_name="THREE";
    card[40].card_type="club";
    card[40].card_value=3;
    card[40].dealt=false;
    card[41].card_name="FOUR";
    card[41].card_type="club";
    card[41].card_value=4;
    card[41].dealt=false;
    card[42].card_name="FIVE";
    card[42].card_type="club";
    card[42].card_value=5;
    card[42].dealt=false;
    card[43].card_name="SIX";
    card[43].card_type="club";
    card[43].card_value=6;
    card[43].dealt=false;
    card[44].card_name="SEVEN";
    card[44].card_type="club";
    card[44].card_value=7;
    card[44].dealt=false;
    card[45].card_name="EIGHT";
    card[45].card_type="club";
    card[45].card_value=8;
    card[45].dealt=false;
    card[46].card_name="NINE";
    card[46].card_type="club";
    card[46].card_value=9;
    card[46].dealt=false;
    card[47].card_name="TEN";
    card[47].card_type="club";
    card[47].card_value=10;
    card[47].dealt=false;
    card[48].card_name="ACE";
    card[48].card_type="club";
    card[48].card_value=1;
    card[48].dealt=false;
    card[49].card_name="JACK";
    card[49].card_type="club";
    card[49].card_value=10;
    card[49].dealt=false;
    card[50].card_name="QUEEN";
    card[50].card_type="club";
    card[50].card_value=10;
    card[50].dealt=false;
    card[51].card_name="KING";
    card[51].card_type="club";
    card[51].card_value=10;
    card[51].dealt=false;
    }
void play_cards::printdeck()
    {
         //loop to print all cards
           for (i=0; i<=51; ++i)
            {
            if((i==13)||(i==26)||(i==39))
                cout<<endl;
              cout<<card[i].card_name<<" "<<card[i].card_type<<" " <<card[i].card_value<<" " +card[i].dealt<<endl;
            }//for loop
    }

void play_cards::reshuffle()
{
    cout<<"**********"<<endl<<
    "The Cards has been reshuffled"<<endl<<
    "**********"<<endl;

    for (i=0; i<=51; ++i)
    {
        card[i].dealt=false;
    }
    counter =0;
}
```

> Could you check this function

```
void play_cards::check()
{

srand(time(NULL));
     random= rand() %53;  //number between 0 and 53



    while(card[random].dealt!=0)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        random= rand() %53; 
    }

     if(!card[random].dealt)
    {
        counter =counter+1;
    }

    if(counter==37)
    {
        reshuffle();
    }


}

void play_cards::startGame()
{


        cout<<endl<<endl;
            int player_wins = 0;
            int computer_wins = 0;
            string choice = "";
            string playerOption = "";
            while(choice!="No")
            {
            bool player_flag = false;
            int player_score = 0;
            int computer_score = 0;
            load();


            check();
            player_score = player_score + card[random].card_value;
            cout<<"Player draws: "<< card[random].card_name<<" "<<card[random].card_type <<endl<<"Score becomes: "<<player_score<<endl<<endl;
            card[random].dealt=1;


            check();
            computer_score = computer_score + card[random].card_value;
            cout<<"Dealer draws: "<< card[random].card_name<<" "<<card[random].card_type<<endl<< "Score becomes: "<<computer_score<<endl<<endl;
            card[random].dealt=1;


            check();
            player_score = player_score + card[random].card_value;
            cout<<"Player draws: "<< card[random].card_name<<" "<<card[random].card_type <<endl<<"Score becomes: "<<player_score<<endl<<endl;
            card[random].dealt=1;


            check();
            computer_score = computer_score + card[random].card_value;
            int hidden = random;
            cout<<"Dealer draws but the value will be shown later " <<endl<<endl;
            card[random].dealt=1;

            cout<<"You want to hit or stand? "<<endl<<endl;
            cin>>playerOption;
             while(playerOption!="stand")
            {
              if(playerOption=="hit")
                {

                    check();
                    player_score = player_score + card[random].card_value;
                    cout<<"Player draws: "<< card[random].card_name<<" "<<card[random].card_type <<endl<<" Score becomes: "<<player_score<<endl<<endl;
                    card[random].dealt=1;
                    if(player_score>21)
                    {
                        cout<<"Player Loses"<<endl;
                        computer_wins=computer_wins+1;
                        player_flag = true;
                        break;

                    }
                    if(player_score==21)
                    {
                        cout<<"Player Wins!!"<<endl;
                        player_wins=player_wins+1;
                        player_flag=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
              cout<<"You want to hit or stand? "<<endl;
            cin>>playerOption;
             }
              if(!player_flag)
            {
                cout<<"Dealer hidden card is: "<< card[hidden].card_name<<" "<<card[hidden].card_type<< "\nScore becomes: "<<computer_score<<endl<<endl;
                bool computer_flag = false;
                    while(computer_score<17)
                    {


                        check();
                        if(card[random].card_name=="ACE")
                        {
                            if(((computer_score+11) >= 17 ) && ((computer_score+11)<=21))
                            {
                                computer_score = computer_score+11;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                computer_score= computer_score+1;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            computer_score = computer_score+card[random].card_value;
                        }
                         cout<<"Dealer draws: "<< card[random].card_name<<" "<<card[random].card_type <<endl<<"Score becomes: "<<computer_score<<endl<<endl;
                         card[random].dealt=1;
                        if(computer_score>21)
                        {
                            cout<<"Dealer loses!!"<<endl;
                            player_wins=player_wins+1;
                            computer_flag= true;
                            break;
                        }
                         if(computer_score==21)
                        {
                            cout<<"Dealer Wins!!"<<endl;
                            computer_wins=computer_wins+1;
                            computer_flag = true;
                            break;
                        }
                         }
                    if(!computer_flag)
                    {
                    if(computer_score>player_score)
                    {
                        cout<<"Dealer Wins!!"<<endl;
                        computer_wins=computer_wins+1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(computer_score<player_score)
                        {
                            cout<<"Player Wins!!"<<endl;
                            player_wins=player_wins+1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout<<"Nobody wins or loses"<<endl;
                        }
                    }
                    }
            }
              Total=Total+1;
              cout<<"counter ="<<counter<<endl;
              cout<<" Do you want to play again? (Yes / No)"<<endl;
              cin>>choice;

    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Final Summary:"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Total Number of played games: "<<Total<<endl;
    cout<<"Player Wins: "<<player_wins<<endl;
    cout<<"Computer Wins: "<<computer_wins<<endl;
    cout<<"The percentage of wins for the playes: "<<(player_wins/Total)*100<<"%"<<endl;

    }
```

Comment: Seed the random generator *once*, at the beginning of the program.

Comment: Take a look at the `<random>` header.

Comment: load all cards into an array or vector, use [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to randomize it, and then start taking cards from the front or back.  Once you get to the opposite side of the container, re-shuffle the container and start again.

Answer (score 1):

You're messing up a bit with the probabilities here. At the beginning you have 52 cards, so you use rand()%52 to get a number between 0 and 51 (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/). This is correct because the probability of each card to be extracted is 1/52.

However as cards get less and less the probability of a single card to be extracted has to raise accordingly. Moreover, your solution is inefficient because when just one card remains you keep extracting until you don't get exactly that value wasting a lot of time.

You can rethink at the problem as a **random permutation of a finite set**, solvable with *Knuth shuffle*, which is very easy to implement. Link to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Thank you so much!